# Typescript treating a object literal as a contract interface / type

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm writing a test where I'm creating an object literal. For example:

```
const myObject = {
  id: 1,
  name: 'egg',
  error: null
}
```

The initialised value for `myObject.error` is null. However, when I try set it to a new value later on. For example:

```
myObject.error = ['exception', 'mapping']
```

I assign it a new value of `string[]` but I get an error:

```
Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'null'.ts(2322)
```

myObject is not an interface or a type so why does it expect it to always be a null value?

Thanks!

Comment: It does have a type.
`type MyObjectType = typeof myObject`.
would look like I think:

   {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    error: null;
  }

Comment: Fast and dirty fix: https://tsplay.dev/WvYVBm

Comment: @Tommos yep, you're correct, thanks

Comment: I would make error and empty array and then you can use error.length to check for errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That happens because you didn't specifically define any other type for the `myObject` const, which will lead to TypeScript assigning the following type definition by default:

```
const myObject: {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    error: null;
}
```

Yeah, `null` is a TypeScript type, and obviously, `string[]` is not compatibale with that. You can however, define the type yourself, and make it compatible like so:

```
type ObjectType = {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    error: null | string[];
}

const myObject: ObjectType = {
  id: 1,
  name: 'egg',
  error: null
}

myObject.error = ['exception', 'mapping']
```

This way, you are letting TypeScript know, that `myObject.error` can either assume the `null` or `string[]` type values.

Comment: Thank you kind sir - and for the detailed explanation :)

Answer (score 1):

TypeScript infers (guesses) the type of `myObject`, in your case it's:

```
{
    id: number;
    name: string;
    error: null;
}
```

When you try to assign to `error` it fails as it's expecting `null`. You could create an interface:

```
interface Produce {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    error: string[] | null;
}

const myObject: Produce = {
  id: 1,
  name: 'egg',
  error: null
};

myObject.error = ['a']; // <== This works
```

Regarding the usage of `null`, you could use an optional `T?` instead, which is equivalent to `T | undefined`:

```
interface Produce {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    error?: string[];
}

const myObject: Produce = {
  id: 1,
  name: 'egg'
};
```